# Declaration of generic return type that corresponds to body argument?

Tags: java

I'm reading through some code that has this line snippet:

```
    public <T> ResponseEntity<T> createResponse(T body, HttpStatus httpStatus) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(body, httpStatus);
  }
```

Just curious why this statement needs the first `<T>` (Within the `public <T>` part of the contract)?

UPDATE (Doing some brain storming based on the comments discussion): Also suppose the contract were written like this:

```
    public <T> ResponseEntity<Person> createResponse(T body, HttpStatus httpStatus) {
    ... Do something with the T body to create the person response.
    return new ResponseEntity<>(person, httpStatus);
  }
```

This would not really make sense right, since the there is no reason to have a method argument with a generic type declared like this?

Comment: Java is a very verbose language. Instead of guessing that `T` is a generic type, you need to declare that. That way there is no guessing involved. The `<T>` does this for you.

Comment: Aha!  Got it.  Thanks. So I assume that the initial <T> works for both the ResponseEntity<T> and the T body parts of the code.  Also if for example the method returned ResponseEntity<Person> but still took a generic T body argument would the the declaration stay the same...still have the first <T> parameter in front of the RepsponseEntity<Person>?

Comment: if you want the parameter to be type `T`, then you still need the declaration. Although, in that case it is not really needed. It would be the same if you did `public ResponseEntity<Person> createResponse(Object body, HttpStatus httpStatus)`

Comment: At some point this `T` needs to be declared. This could also be a class specific typ, then it could also stand at the class declaration like `public class MyClass<T>` for example. In this case you would not need to additionally declare it at the method. But if this is a method-specific type then you use the code you have shown us to declare it.

Comment: T is a generic type need to be added before method return type for generic method . So argument for method createResponse did the type interference for type parameter T at compile time.